# How to combine two DataFrames by tail of the first and head of the second?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to combine two DataFrames by tail of the first and head of the second?
For example there are two DataFrames.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, 1, 2, 1, 2], 'col2': [0, 1, 2, 1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3], 'col2': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]})

   col1  col2
0     0     0
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     1     1
4     2     2

   col1  col2
0     1     1
1     2     2
2     1     1
3     2     2
4     3     3
```

I need to combine them to

```
   col1  col2
0     0     0
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     1     1
4     2     2
5     3     3
```

Comment: please show us what you have tried

Comment: based on what logic, can you please explain a little

Comment: Also do you mean this way? `pd.concat([df1[~df1.eq(df2.shift())],df2]).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)`